# Change the design of email body

Tags: email, meteor, mailgun

I have written the code for sending email in email.js as follows:

```
Accounts.emailTemplates.siteName = "xyz";
Accounts.emailTemplates.from     = "xyz <admin@xyz.com>";

Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail = {
    subject() {
        return "[xyz] Verify Your Email Address";
    }
};

Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.text = function( user, url) {
    let emailAddress   = user.emails[0].address,
    urlWithoutHash = url.replace( '', '' ),
    supportEmail   = "support@xyz.com",
    emailBody      = `To verify your email address (${emailAddress}) visit the following link:\n\n${urlWithoutHash}\n\n If you did not request this verification, please ignore this email. If you feel something is wrong, please contact our support team: ${supportEmail}.`;
    return emailBody;   
}
```

The email is working and all I want is to change the Design. How to design the email body? Can I insert the html code inside the email body so that I can have a proper responsive email design? I have tried in many ways. Can anyone please help me out?

I have used mail gun API for sending emails is there anyway to use template.

I have tried with grunt email template and am struck with that I need help to get complete my task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create an email template using [SSR](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-ssr) package.

```
Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.html = function (user, url) {
       SSR.compileTemplate( 'registartionEmail', Assets.getText( 'email_templates/registration_confirm.html' ) );
       var emailData = {
              x: y;
       };
       return SSR.render( 'registartionEmail', emailData );
};
```

Comment: verification email is done and is working successfully thank you for helping  and ... for contact and forgot password email via mailgun api... how I should approach can you please help me..out

Comment: Let me know how can I help you.

Comment: I have created the helpers and events for forgot password following way

Comment: You just need to change verifyEmail to resetPassword like : Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.html or .subject. Rest of the thing remain same.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40085191/reset-password-email-templates

Comment: for contact email 
user can send an email if he has any query regarding the website .. for that i have created a contact form as if now a normal email without any design is working i want to insert a email template. help me in this yar

Answer (score 0):

To handle the process of converting templates into raw HTML on the server, you need to add a package to your application called meteorhacks:ssr. Once you have the package installed, you can store plain HTML files inside your /private directory and then convert them later, passing any data to replace handlebars helpers like {{name}} in the process.

For example, here is some code I have used to send a welcome email when new users register:

```
import { SSR } from 'meteor/meteorhacks:ssr';

const getHTMLForEmail = (templateName, data) => {
  SSR.compileTemplate(templateName, Assets.getText(`email/templates/${templateName}.html`));
  return SSR.render(templateName, data);
};

const sendEmail = (emailAddress, html) => {
  if (emailAddress.includes('@')) {
    const emailData = {
      to: emailAddress,
      from: 'Test Email <hello@test.io>',
      subject: 'Welcome aboard, team matey!',
      html,
    };

    Meteor.defer(() => Email.send(emailData));
  }
};

export const sendWelcomeEmail = (user, profile) => {
  let email;
  if (user.services.facebook) {
    email = user.services.facebook.email;
  } else if (user.services.google) {
    email = user.services.google.email;
  }

  const data = {
    email,
    name: profile && profile.name ? profile.name : '',
    url: 'www.google.com',
  };
  const html = getHTMLForEmail( 'welcome-email', data );

  sendEmail(data.email, html);
};
```

You will find the following two articles from Meteor Chef very useful (also shows how the html email template looks like):

1. [Using the email package](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/using-the-email-package/)
2. [Sign up with email verification](https://themeteorchef.com/snippets/sign-up-with-email-verification/)

Comment: Thank you so much .. Now I got the clear picture that how to work on this ...thank you!!

Comment: I have referred the links you have given that helped me alot thank youu and verification email is done and is working successfully and ... for contact and forgot password email via mailgun api... how I should approach can you please help me..out

Comment: I suggest you create a new question for that

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40085191/reset-password-email-templates